# How can I download youtube playlist using UGet download manager?

Tags: 20.04, uget

How to download youtube playlist using [Ugetdm](https://ugetdm.com/)

Comment: would you be willing to try `youtube-dl`?

Comment: I need to use Uget since I don't like to use another programme

Comment: if you don't like that `youtube-dl` is command based then you might want to try `JDownloader`. it has a GUI. In my opinion it even looks nicer than `Uget`.

Comment: Gydl (Graphical Youtube-dl) is a GUI wrapper around the already existing youtube-dl program. To install Gydl in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type `sudo snap install gydl`